# How to include forward slash and dots in PHP preg_match_all?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

My PHP code looks like :

```
preg_match_all("/\|\w+\|/s", $str, $pat_array1);
```

When I am using

```
str = 'For detail check this site |mysite|.'
```

I am getting output as :

```
Array
(
    [0] => |mysite|
)
```

But when I am using forward slash or dot(.), I'm not getting the correct output.
For Example if :

```
str = 'For detail check this site |mysite.com/parm1/parm2?val=1|.'
```

then my output is a blank array like:

```
Array
(
)
```

For this case I want to get output like

```
Array
(
    [0] => |mysite.com/parm1/parm2?val=1|
)
```

Comment: `preg_match_all("/\|.*?\|/s", $str, $pat_array1);` or `preg_match_all("/\|[^|]*\|/", $str, $pat_array1);` will work.

Comment: Your question has been marked duplicate, but one sensible thing to do when trying to match metacharacters is to place them inside brackets, e.g. use `[./]` to match literal dot or forward slash.

Comment: Because `.` and `/` are not word characters.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That worked! Thanks.